# How to show icons use QSqlRelationalTableModel and QTableView in every row

Tags: qt, qtableview

Now,I am try to use QSqlRelationalTableModel and QTableView to show my data in database,according to the properity "fileType" such as "doc,txt,exe,sln" to show a icon in the first column.

```
    dirModel=new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this);
    dirModel->setTable("ecm_doc");
    dirModel->setFilter(QString("creatoruserid='%1' and parentid='%2'").arg(userid).arg(parentid));
    dirModel->select();
    dirView=new QTableView(this);
    dirView->setItemDelegate(new DirDelegate(this));

    dirView->setModel(dirModel);
    dirView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);

     showIcon();

void DirTree::showIcon()
{
    int rowCount = dirModel->rowCount();
    for(int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
    {
//here is a test.
        QModelIndex index = dirModel->index(row, 1);
        QIcon folderIcon(style()->standardPixmap(QStyle::SP_DirClosedIcon));
        dirModel->setData(index, folderIcon, Qt::DecorationRole);
    }
}
```

Help me,online wait:)

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass from `QSqlRelationalTableModel` and reimplement the [`data()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqlrelationaltablemodel.html#data) function in order to specify the icon:

```
QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    // I assume that 1 is the db table column with the filetype property 
    if (index.column() == 1 && role == Qt::DecorationRole)
    {
       QSqlRecord r = modelRecord(index.row());
       QString fileType = r.field(1).value().toString();

       QIcon icon; 
       if (fileType == "exe")
          icon = QIcon(":/PathToIcon/exe.png");
       else if (fileType == "sln")
          icon = QIcon(":/PathToIcon/sln.png"); 
       ...
       return QVariant(icon);
    }

    return QSqlRelationalTableModel::data(index, role);
}
```

Comment: Well,you help me a lot but how can i get the modelRecord object?I Should i get it from base class QSqlRelationalTableModel? I only overwrite "data" method.QVariant SqlTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &item, int role) const
{
    if(role==Qt::DecorationRole)
    {
        QSqlRecord r = modelRecord(item.row());
        return   getIconFromType(r.field(9).value().toString());
    }
    return    QSqlRelationalTableModel::data(item,role);
}

Comment: Thank you very much,i read my book and got it.`QVariant SqlTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &item, int role) const
{
    if(role==Qt::DecorationRole&&item.column()==Doc_DocType)
    {
        QSqlRecord r=this->record(item.row());
     return   QVariant(getIconFromType(r.field(Doc_DocType).value().toString()));
    }
    return    QSqlRelationalTableModel::data(item,role);
}`